# Is there a way to arrange Azure pipelines in some tree like structure?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have Azure pipelines for multiple repos. In the Azure DevOps UI, is there a way to arrange them in some structure based on either repo or repo+branch?

Currently they are all shown in one big list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipelines view, click `all` tab. There you'll have option to create folders. To move a pipeline, click three dots button next to its name and select `rename/move`.

[image]

Unfortunatelly, there's no way to make this view the default.